# Facebook FQL API - Who tagged user?

Tags: facebook, api, tags, facebook-fql, photos

I am able to retrieve tags on statuses and photos just fine.  I know the fact that my user has been tagged.

For posts, (stream_tag) it's easy to assess who did the tagging since the author of the status is by definition the tagger.

I am using FQL to query photo_tag table to obtain a pid and then querying the photo table to get photo information...

However, I am trying to ascertain who is the tagger of a user in a photo.  People can tag other peoples photos, and I get all that, but I would like the attribution....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  Looking at a photo on Facebook doesn't show who added each photo tag; it makes sense that the API doesn't give you this information either.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot read the tagger info, unfortunately. first, because you don´t even see it on facebook directly. and there is no column for this info in the photo_tag table:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/